# Saber si han transcurrido X minutos desde cierta acción

Tags: python, micropython

Estoy trabajando con un microcontrolador que tiene una clase RTC. Si yo hago `rtc.now()` me devuelve una tupla cómo la siguiente `(2021, 4, 26, 15, 3, 2, 218653, None)`.

Documentación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría saber si X tiempo después vuelvo a hacer un `rtc.now()` si puedo obtener el tiempo que ha pasado. Es decir, quiero saber si existe una manera ya hecha, sin tener que hacer múltiples `if-else` que tengan en cuenta si ha cambiado el minuto, la hora, etc. Obviamente se podría pero me parece muy enrevesado.

[Documentación](https://docs.pycom.io/firmwareapi/pycom/machine/rtc/).

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Pregunto: ¿Tienes permitido usar `datetime` allí? Porque puedes valerte de ese tipo de objetos para hacerlo muy fácilmente (solo restando el más antiguo del más nuevo).

Comment: No pero he visto tiene una clase clock que se puede implementar un crono! Por lo tanto, puedo solucionarlo por allí.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Micropython hay varias funciones para trabajar con intervalos de tiempo.

**utime.ticks_ms()**

Devuelve una cuenta de milisegundos. El punto de partida no está explícitamente definido, pues sólo interesa para sacar diferencias.

**utime.ticks_diff(ticks1, ticks2)**

Calcula la diferencia entre dos tiempos obtenidos con `utime.ticks_ms` y retorna los milisegundos entre uno u otro (ticks1 - ticks2).

La razón de usar estas funciones (y no los valores numéricos directamente), es que la cantidad de milisegundos no puede crecer indefinidamente; en algún momento la cuenta vuelve a cero y comienza de nuevo.

Por tal razón, no es tan simple como decir `ticks1 - ticks2`; hay que considerar la posibilidad de que el tiempo posterior este representado por un valor numérico menor.

Este trozo de código ejecuta una determina operación cada un mínuto. Para hacerlo exacto, calcula el tiempo ocupado en ejecutar la función y luego hace un `sleep` por el tiempo que falta hasta el próximo minuto:

```
while True:
        start_ms = time.ticks_ms()
        try:
            c = MQTTClient("umqtt_client", "172.16.0.1")
            c.connect()
            # Arma un json con datos para transmitir.
            c.publish(b"sensor/data", json, retain=True)
            c.disconnect()
        except OSError as e:
            print("Error MQTTClient:", e)
            machine.reset()

        #   Tiempo de ejecución variable de 1ms a 270ms

        diff = time.ticks_diff(time.ticks_ms(), start_ms)

        await uasyncio.sleep_ms(60000 - diff)
```